# Python + reportlab = многостраничный PDF из XML: Таблица идет сплошная, не разделяясь на страницы

Tags: python, python-3.x

Сильно ну критикуйте, я новичек в программировании. Подскажите как сделать многостраничный PDF, в Гугле есть решения, для определенного текста, а у меня он парсится из XML.

Таблица идет сплошная, не разделяясь на страницы. Помогите пожалуйста, не могу решить данную задачу

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from lxml import etree, objectify
from reportlab.lib.styles import getSampleStyleSheet
from reportlab.lib.units import inch, mm
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from reportlab.platypus import Paragraph, Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter

pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont('FreeSans', 'FreeSans.ttf'))

class PDFOrder(object):

    def __init__(self, xml_file, pdf_file):
        """Constructor"""
        self.xml_file = xml_file
        self.pdf_file = pdf_file
        self.xml_obj = self.getXMLObject()

    def coord(self, x, y, unit=1):
        x, y = x * unit, self.height -  y * unit
        return x, y

    def createPDF(self):
        """
        Создаём PDF на основании XML данных
        """
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.pdf_file, pagesize=letter)
        width, self.height = letter
        styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
        xml = self.xml_obj

        order_number='<font name="FreeSans"><b>Отчет биллинговой системы </b></font>'
        p = Paragraph(order_number, styles["Normal"])
        p.wrapOn(self.canvas, width, self.height)
        p.drawOn(self.canvas, *self.coord(18, 10, mm))

        data = []
        data.append(["Дата платежа", "Дата регистрации", "Адрес", "Лиц.счет", "Сумма"])

        for payment in xml.answer.findall('payment'):
             row = []
             row.append(payment.get('payment_date'))
             row.append(payment.get('recieved_date'))
             row.append(payment.get('address'))
             row.append(payment.get('account'))
             row.append(payment.get('amount'))
             data.append(row)
        data.append([])
        t = Table(data)
        t.setStyle(TableStyle((
            ('INNERGRID', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
            ('BOX', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 0.25, colors.black),
            ('TEXTCOLOR', (0, 0), (-1, -1), colors.blue),
            ('ALIGN', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'CENTER'),
            ('FONTNAME', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 'FreeSans'),
            ('FONTSIZE', (0, 0), (-1, -1), 8)
        )))
        t.wrapOn(self.canvas, width, self.height)
        t.drawOn(self.canvas, *self.coord(18, 385, mm))
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def getXMLObject(self):
        """
        Открываем XML документ и возвращаем lxml XML документ
        """
        with open(self.xml_file) as f:
            xml = f.read()
            xml = bytes(bytearray(xml, encoding='utf-8'))
        return objectify.fromstring(xml)
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def savePDF(self):
        """
        Сохраняем PDF
        """
if __name__ == "__main__":
     xml = "payments.xml"
     pdf = "letter2.pdf"
     doc = PDFOrder(xml, pdf)
     doc.createPDF()
     doc.savePDF()[
```

Comment: 1- не имеет значения что ввод xml. Примеры по созданию многостраничного pdf  с reportlab не перестанут работать откуда бы входной текст не появлялся 2- не нужно весь код, который у вас есть в вопрос помещать. Создайте минимальный пример, который демонстрирует проблему [mcve] Явно словами опишите что хотели получить и что конкретно вместо этого происходит. Явно минимальный пример ввода укажите.

Comment: Это часть кода. Хотелось бы разобраться как разделить таблицу на несколько страниц. Была задумка привязываться к __len_ и количеству строчек, на первой странице допустим 20, на другой 60. Но строчки могут иметь разную высоту (в зависимости от данных). Я думаю это кривое решение. Второй вариант указать допустимую область заполнения страницы, в частности снизу. Как это сделать не могу понять или я не в том направлении иду?

Comment: Хотелось бы получить таблицу которая автоматически переходила на другую страницу и имела подзаголовок.